# Migrate WP Menu between sites

Tags: menus

What Wordpress tables contain the nav menus?

I am getting conflicting information like `wp-options`, `wp_terms`, `wp_term_taxonomy`, `wp_term_relationships`. the information is all 4 years old though.

I just want to export my menu from one site then import it into another.  I want the whole structure.

I tried the WP export function but there isn't a way to just select the menu system, and I wasn't sure I could import just the nav menu section.

thanks in advance,
D

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin a while back and it worked well, although the menu system wasn't overtly complex, just had lots of items. https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-exporter/ - It's old, but could still do the trick. This will let you export your menu and import via the standard importer tool.